# Post Method in Angular 6 not sending data

Tags: c#, api, http-post, angular6

When i am doing api call with get it works perfect when i convert to post its giving me null value in parameter. I have to use [FromBody] then only api gets called but still gives me parameter value null. I have handled the CORS also.

```
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({      
    'Content':"application/json",
    'Content-Type':  'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    //'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(Username + ":" + Password),        
  }),         
};

 checkLogin(form){        
    var obj = { Business_Email: form["Business_Email"], Business_Password: form["Business_Password"] };        
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL+"/Login/LoginValid", JSON.stringify(obj),httpOptions)


  }
```

I have the Web Api in Asp .net C#

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("LoginValid")]
        [Route("api/Login/LoginValid")]
        public ReturnObject LoginValid([FromBody]string businessMaster)
        {
           //Code
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar code that is working fine with angular 6.

```
addEmployee(emp: Employee): Observable<number> {
   return this.http.post(this._baseURL + "/api/employee", emp).pipe(
    map(success => success.status))
   }



[HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Employee employee)
        {
            db.Employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: Does it has anything to do with headers? Mine is not working though our codes are same

Comment: just declare http as  constructor(private http: Http) {}.Remove additional header settings.Hope it will work.

Comment: I was taking string as parameter on web api when i changed to my model type it worked. Thanks i have been working on it from hours.

Answer (score -1):

To trigger the http.post method you have to subscribe to it somewhere. See the angular api https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request

"Always subscribe! An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods."

Comment: I have already subscribed it in my Login Component    :                                                    this.data.checkLogin(this.loginForm.value)
    .subscribe()